# Which message pattern should I use for synchronous communincation in Nodejs Microservices?

Tags: rest, microservices

My Nodejs microservices currently running on Kubernetes are communicating over REST. Does the request-reply model of NATS, which replier needs to return (large data ~ 500kb currently single endpoint response), cause performance increase? Some benchmarks say it's 10 times faster [1], but I got a bad result on a little test I did at my local (but the conditions weren't equal, I'll repeat the test on more equal terms). On the other hand, I have read that RabbitMQ does not have a good performance on request-reply. I want to discuss here, how can I decide which communication model is advantageous / performance in situations that require synchronous communication?

In addition, when REST is used, resources can be documented with Swagger. What needs to be done when using NATS?

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNQM_aq9pd4&ab_channel=VinothSelvaraj
2. https://www.vinsguru.com/nats-performance-comparison-with-rest/

Comment: This seems a bit broad.  If your performance test is broken, fix your test and run it again.

Comment: I read all the docs and did some research. I want to hear the experiences. Tests are not broken, I got better responses with REST, but there wasn't a Gateway layer and I sent the requests directly to the service, while the application that I've downloaded that uses NATS was including an additional layer.